# Flask: login session times out too soon

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login

While editing a record, if there is a long wait of let say a few minutes (getting coffee) and then coming back to press the save (POST), I get redirected to the main page to login instead and the data is lost.

It seems the flask-login session expires too fast.

I did some research and came across this.

```
from flask import session, app

session.permanent = True
```

Is this the proper way to go?  But even when I try this I get this exception:

```
  File "/Users/kave/workspace/F11A/src/application/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    session.permanent = True
  File "/Users/kave/workspace/F11A/src/lib/werkzeug/local.py", line 355, in <lambda>
    __setattr__ = lambda x, n, v: setattr(x._get_current_object(), n, v)
  File "/Users/kave/workspace/F11A/src/lib/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/kave/workspace/F11A/src/lib/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

Comment: what version of flask are you using ?

Comment: Version 0.10.  I just upgraded to 0.10.1.

Comment: ok. I asked because in latest version 0.10, there were some changes made to the sessions including adding a SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST config flag which may or may be the issue. Also, Request Context that handles sessions have been changed. Can you check the value of SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST config flag ? It seems like when you hit the back button, it might be a new request which then refreshes the session ?

Comment: `SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST` is currently not in my setting.py.  Do I have to set it to `False` explicitly?

Comment: i would think so. Give it a shot.

Comment: Check the expiration date in the session cookie using your browser's debugger. Based on what I see in the source code the session should expire 31 days from the date it was set.

Comment: The `SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST` configuration option is not available in 0.10.1. As of this comment, it is not available in a stable release of Flask.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone else will have this question. I suppose  Hooman already got answer.

**Won`t work**

views.py

```
from flask import session
from datetime import timedelta

session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)
```

**Will work**

```
from flask import session
from datetime import timedelta

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_work():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)
    form = MyForm(request.form)
    return render_template('home.html', form = form)
```

`session` must be used inside the request.

Answer (score 5):

If you try to access the session object like this it won't work.

As the error message says, `flask.session` can only be used from within a [request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/#the-request-context), which won't exist at that point. You should only use it from within a route.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Move the code that's touching your session inside of a view, don't put it elsewhere since there is no concept of a session outside of a 'request'.

Comment: session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)   should be in the login function/view,   or in each route/request?