# set persistent cookie with python flask

Tags: cookies, flask, persistent

I'm trying to use a cookie to remember if a visitor has already seen a particular tutorial page on my site. The site is build using Flask.

The tutorial page gets loaded from flask routing so I thought it made sense to try and alter the cookie in the flask routing definition using the make_response and response.set_cookie function from the flask framework.

However, this (session) cookie is only for the duration of the session. 
I can't find any info on setting permanent/persistent cookies with flask. How can I do this with flask ?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `flask-login`. It provides [remember be](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#remember-me) functionality. You can also find an example of using it in Miguel Gringerg's [flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Flask-login does however feel a bit like overkill just to add a property to a cookie. No other ways to change the persistent cookie?

Comment: can [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783025/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-sessions-timeout-in-flask) be helpful?
Also, make sure you use `session.permanent` properly (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662558/flask-login-session-times-out-too-soon))

Comment: thanks again for the pointers. Much appreciated. Looked at it, tried it, but in the end just used javascript to make he cookie....

Answer (score 8):

To set a persistent cookie, you must add the "expires" field in the http header:

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Expires=<date>
```

If you don't provide `Expires=`, then the browser considers the cookie as a "session" cookie and deletes the cookie when the browser is closed.

For Flask, you can use the parameter `expires=` of the response.set_cookie() function like this for a 30-days cookie:

```
import datetime
response.set_cookie(name, value,
                    expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30))
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions a session cookie. Assuming that means `Flask.session` is being used, [`session.permanent = True`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.session.permanent) is the official way to toggle the `Expires` header on the `session` cookie. The value can be specified either in the Flask config (using `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME `) or by setting `app.permanent_session_lifetime`.